# Configuring Apple News

Tags: plugin-applenews

I installed the plugin for Apple News (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AppleNews) but did not understand the configuration instructions.

I created a file at `craft/config/applenews.php` with the following:

```
<?php

return [
'channels' => [
    [
        'class'     => 'applenewschannels.MyNewsChannel',
        'channelId' => 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'apiKeyId'  => 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'apiSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ],
  ],
];
```

I created a `craft/applenewschannels` folder and added `MyNewsChannel.php` and `MyNewsArticle.php` but the “Apple News Channels” pane has not appeared on the edit entry page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and solved it by ensuring that the locale checked against in the `matchEntry()` function in `MyNewsChannel.php` matched the locale of my site.

The [example channel class](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AppleNews/blob/master/applenewschannels/MyNewsChannel.php) provided in the plugin repo checks for a site locale set to `en` on line 27:

`if ($entry->locale != 'en') {
return false;
}`

My site locale was set to `en_us`; correcting it in my channel class solved this for me. Maybe this is also the case for you or someone else who has landed here with a similar issue!